# Strange behaviour when editing c and cpp files after update

Tags: vimrc, filetype

After updating vim, it behaves very irrationally when I try to edit a `c` or `cpp` file. Here is a picture:

[image: screenshot]

I have tried to debug a bit, and both

```
vim -u NORC -N --cmd 'call pathogen#infect()' file.c
```

and

```
vim --noplugin file.c
```

eliminates the problem, which is strange, as the first one uses plugins but no vimrc, and the second one vimrc but no plugins.

I am indeed using pathogen and if relevant (or actually, regardless of that), here are the plugins I'm using: `nerdcommenter`, `vim-airline`, `vim-glsl`, `vim-session`, `nerdtree`, `vim-airlineish`, `vim-gradle`, `YouCompleteMe`, `TagHighlight`, `vim-autoclose`, `vim-misc`

This is my `.vimrc`: https://bpaste.net/show/9910268a2e20

I tried to debug using `:finish`, and found out that the error is caused by line 69:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Same thing if I replace it by:

```
filetype on
```

But that's maybe obvious as the problem seems to only happen (as far as I have tried) on c and cpp files.

Comment: Try commenting out your plugin settings plugin by plugin in your vimrc. Do you have any custom `ftplugin` files? Your vimrc has the call to pathogen commented out.

Comment: I uncommented pathogen, and commented out all the plugin settings, but I still have the problem. I have `ftdetect/z80.vim`; I also tried `vim a.c` while that directory is empty. Also, clearing my `bundle` directory, the problem persists.. How does that differ from `vim --noplugin file.c`?

Comment: Had a similar problem. Disabling clang-complete worked for me.

Comment: @cabellicar123 in this case, the most similar plugin would be YouCompleteMe, I suppose.

Comment: @muru Yes that would appear correct. I seems related to the recent ncurses update. Here's some info info: https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues/453 and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=202590.

Comment: Thanks for responses. However, vim still behaves incorrectly when I move _all_ plugins to a temporary directory - that is, I empty the `bundle` directory. And it still does seem entierly dependent on the `filetype` line in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Solution: there were some clang-related files in `.vim/plugin`. I don't know how they got there, but deleting `plugin` solved the problem.